# pandas fill column with values based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a column in my pandas dataframe like so:

```
   Status
1  Past Due
2  Yet to Calc
3  Overdue
4  Past Due
5  Past Due
6  Yet to Calc
7  Past Due
8  Past Due
9  Past Due
10  Yet to Calc
11  Overdue
12  Yet to Calc
13  Past Due
14  Past Due
15  Past Due
16  Yet to Calc
17  Overdue
18  Past Due
19  Past Due
20  Past Due
21  Yet to Calc
```

I want to fill all values between 'Overdue' and 'Yet to Calc' with 'Overdue'. So my expected output is:

```
   Status
1  Past Due
2  Yet to Calc
3  Overdue
4  Overdue
5  Overdue
6  Yet to Calc
7  Past Due
8  Past Due
9  Past Due
10 Yet to Calc
11 Overdue
12 Yet to Calc
13 Past Due
14 Past Due
15 Past Due
16 Yet to Calc
17 Overdue
18 Overdue
19 Overdue
20 Overdue
21 Yet to Calc
```

I tried grouping by slices and filling forward within the group like so:

```
df3['Inventory_1'] = df3.groupby(df3.loc['Overdue':'Yet to Calc','Inventory_1']).ffill()
```

But the above returns a null series and does not populate.

What is the way to approach this, if not by using ffill?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general idea here is to mask all values that *are not* `Yet to Calc` or `Overdue`, and use `ffill`.  However, this will also `ffill` `Yet to Calc` forward, which is never desired.  Since we only needed to keep the `Yet to Calc` in order to stop the filling of the `Overdue` values, we can replace everything that isn't `Overdue` in our result with whatever it contained in the original DataFrame.

---

#### `mask` + `ffill` + `isin`

```
s = df.Status.mask(~df.Status.isin(['Overdue', 'Yet to Calc'])).ffill()
s[s.ne('Overdue')] = df.Status

print(s)
```

```
1        Past Due
2     Yet to Calc
3         Overdue
4         Overdue
5         Overdue
6     Yet to Calc
7        Past Due
8        Past Due
9        Past Due
10    Yet to Calc
11        Overdue
12    Yet to Calc
13       Past Due
14       Past Due
15       Past Due
16    Yet to Calc
17        Overdue
18        Overdue
19        Overdue
20        Overdue
21    Yet to Calc
Name: Status, dtype: object
```

Comment: A variation of this works perfectly, thanks user3483203!!

Comment: In my original dataset, in case there are other values than Yet to Calc, how would the masking be done? I still need to fill with the 'Overdue' value as long as 'Past Due' occurs, but the Yet to Calc is replaced with random values